After updating work laptop to Windows 11, I get CodeExpectedError: WebSocket close with status code 1006 when starting VS Code in WSL
After updating my work laptop to Win11, I'm unable to connect Visual Studio Code to my WSL instances (Ubuntu and Debian) as I get the error detailed here Vscode cannot connect to remote Linux （_WebSocket close with status code 1006）
I have tried everything inside the above thread.
VS Code 1.95, WSL is updated to current
